# Is there any package in ros2 that like package "rosbridge_suite" in ros1?

Tags: ros, ros2, rosbridge-suite

[image: Rosanswers logo]

recently, we want to upgrade our ros1 project into ros2, but we have a frontend package that using javascript api to call ros pub/sub with the help of "rosbridge_suite",  we are stuck in it, could any one give me some help ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/300714/is-there-any-package-in-ros2-that-like-package-%22rosbridge_suite%22-in-ros1-?/) by [lxbeyond](https://answers.ros.org/users/36253/lxbeyond/) on ROS Answers with karma: 25 on 2018-08-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

`rosbridge_suite` is now available for ROS 2:

https://github.com/RobotWebTools/rosbridge_suite

---

Originally posted by [amacneil](https://answers.ros.org/users/72389/amacneil/) with karma: 26 on 2021-12-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It's not a pure replacement of `rosbridge_suite` iiuc, but perhaps [RobotWebTools/ros2-web-bridge](https://github.com/RobotWebTools/ros2-web-bridge) comes close.

From the readme:

> ros2-web-bridge, which leverages the [rclnodejs](https://github.com/RobotWebTools/rclnodejs) client, provides a JSON interface to [ROS 2.0](https://github.com/ros2/ros2/wiki) by adopting the [rosbridge v2 protocol](https://github.com/RobotWebTools/rosbridge_suite/blob/develop/ROSBRIDGE_PROTOCOL.md). The bridge can process commands through JSON tuneled over WebSockets.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-08-16

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [lxbeyond](https://answers.ros.org/users/36253/lxbeyond/) on 2018-08-16**:
Did it support ros2 bouncy version ?